# Sort with operator overloading in python

Tags: python

I am new to operator overloading so please bear with me. I have a class with operator overloading `__lt__` which is supposed to prints out the sorted result of a list but I'm getting error `'<' not supported between instances of 'Inventory' and 'Inventory'`. Why can't the sort method sort the contents of the list. Where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self, item, cost):
        self.item = item
        self.cost = cost
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "{:16s} ${:6.2f}".format(self.item, self.cost)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return Inventory(self.cost < other.cost)

i1 = Inventory("Pentel Pen", 1.45)
i2 = Inventory("Ruler", .99)
i3 = Inventory("Calculus Text", 245.99)
i4 = Inventory("Diet Coke", 1.80)
t = [i1, i2, i3, i4]
t = [i1, i2, i3, i4]

for i in sorted(t):
    print(i)

Expected result:

Ruler            $  0.99
Pentel Pen       $  1.45
Diet Coke        $  1.80
Calculus Text    $245.99
```

Comment: `return Adder(self.value + other.value + random.randrange(1, 6))`

Comment: I accidentally published the wrong question earlier. I have updated my question to the right one. Apologies for the confusion. @OlvinRoght

Comment: The code you posted says: "TypeError: `__init__()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'cost'" because `Inventory(self.cost < other.cost)` attempts to initialise an instance of `Inventory` providing `self.cost < other.cost` as `item` and nothing as `cost`.

Comment: Do i have to initialize item too something like```Inventory(self.item + "," + str(self.cost) < str(other.cost))```? @ForceBru

Comment: @hamtonko, why? `__lt__(self, other)` should answer the question: "Is `self` less than `other`? Yes or no?" So it should return a Boolean (`True` or `False`). There could be reasons to return something else, but I don't think it makes sense here

Comment: Oh, I got confused for a sec there. I fixed that issue with ```Inventory(self.item, self.cost < other.cost)``` but the return isn't sorted. why is it not sorted?@ForceBru

Comment: @hamtonko, why to not use `key` argument of `sorted()`? `sorted(t, key=lambda x: x.cost)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, I could do that but I'm trying to understand operator overloading that's why.

Comment: @hamtonko, than you forgot to check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__). Quote from docs: *"By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your method with:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.cost < other.cost
```

`inventory1 < inventory2` should return `True` or `False` for sorting to work, not an instance of `Inventory`.